# django app with uwsgi taking long response with requests.post within the views

Tags: python, django

I'm using uwsgi to serve my django application and within my views.py I use requests.post to connect to another server endpoint

Running on manage.py runserver, the views working fine but it takes forever when I use uwsgi

I'm pretty sure requests.post who causing this, as I comment my line that has requests.post, its working okay

Following are my uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODUL=project.settings
harakiri = 1200 # respawn processes taking more than 20 seconds
max-requests = 5000
daemonize = ./backoffice.log
master = true
workers=16
vacuum=true
```

Is it possible this is because sort of thread locking between requests and uwsgi?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is thread lock happening. Just to be sure do something like this:

```
post-buffering = 8192
processes = 4
no-orphans = 1
thunder-lock = true
enable-threads = true
```

If I understood correctly you are firing one request to your django view, and from this view you fire another to a third-party resource, right?

Comment: yes correct
I tried to add you've writen to my uwsgi ini file but the result still the same.
It still hung in lines where I fire another endpoint with requests.post

Comment: Ever figure this out, @ave ?

Comment: sorry for really late reply @RossRogers, I didn't and eventually switch into gunicorn :D

Comment: In my case, the other end point really was freezing on my request, blocking forever.  This caused my system to freeze waiting for the response.  When I resolved this, the system worked again.  I used `strace -f` to track down what was going on at the system call level to utterly prove that it was not python, python's request library, django, or uWSGI.